# How can I export http_proxy in git bash on win10 global

Tags: export, environment-variables, global, git-bash, http-proxy

I usually use git-bash to do some operation like
`go get`,`docker pull`,`curl -i google.com` 
 and so on.

Because I am in China,I need a proxy to programme!

Now I  use
`export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1080` every time,but it is local and provisional,I feel so bother.
Is there a good way to set the http_proxy global and permanent.

Thank you advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For permanent proxy setting set proxy in environment variables.
For more details visit : [click here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/http-proxy.html) or https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/http-proxy.html .
If the idea not works remove https:// in variable value.